# Cannot extract values from dictionary once set in VBA/Access 2003

Tags: ms-access, dictionary, vba

I'm writing a script which pulls out some patient data and generates an XML export.

Each patient record has an associated doctor - but rather than repeat doctor details in each record, I figured I'd set the doctor ID in the patient record, and then include a list of doctors in a different section at the bottom of the document.

One thing I need to do is included a GUID for the doctor in the patient record, but the actual database relationship is a local non-unique ID. I figured the best way forward was to map the GUIDs in a list of local IDs using a dictionary.

Anyway, long story short, here is the bit that builds the require list:

```
While Not PatientRec.EOF
    Set DoctorRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("Select Lng_Key, Txt_GUID From Tbl_LU_DoctorDetail Where Lng_Key = " & PatientRec![Lng_Doctor])

    While Not DoctorRec.EOF
        If (IsNull(DoctorRec![Txt_GUID])) Then
            DoctorRec.Edit
            DoctorRec![Txt_GUID] = CreateGUID()
            DoctorRec.Update
        End If

        DoctorList.Add DoctorRec![Lng_Key], DoctorRec![Txt_GUID]

        ' outputs something like '5:{03f50fe1-a0a4-4733-906a-771e22845ea6}
        MsgBox (DoctorRec![Lng_Key] & ":" & DoctorList.Items(DoctorRec![Lng_Key]))

        DoctorRec.MoveNext
    Wend
Wend

' outputs nothing!
MsgBox (DoctorList.Item(5))

' but there is something in there???
MsgBox (DoctorList.count)
```

I've also tried casting the id to a string using CStr, but get the same result with DoctorList.Item("5")

Worse, when I try:

```
Dim v As Variant
For Each v In DoctorList.Keys
    MsgBox (v & ":" & DoctorList.Item(v))
Next
```

I get the error:

```
Run-time error '3420':

Object invalid or no longer set.
```

Testing (and the helpfile) indicates that the Variant 'v' is not being set to anything from the Keys property, but the For Each is at least attempting on loop...

-- Update

I found a similar question by someone on vbforums: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=622933

I tested with a hardcoded key and item:

```
DoctorList.Add 5, "String"
```

The For Each loop now runs once successfully, but then fails with the 3420 error on a second loop (even when it should have stopped on the first loop).

Comment: The unnecessary parentheses in the `MsgBox` calls can cause issues. Try replacing `MsgBox (DoctorList.Item(5))` with `MsgBox DoctorList.Item(5)` or, if you can't live without parentheses, `Call MsgBox(DoctorList.Item(5))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the problem - it appears that Dictionaries will happily use objects as keys, so when using the Dictionary.Add method you have to explicitly use the Value property of the field from the recordset:

```
DoctorList.Add DoctorRec![Lng_Key].Value, DoctorRec![Txt_GUID].Value
```

Comment: Excellent - Makes sense when you see it as an object in the Dictionary, not a converted value!

Comment: I spent an hour trying to figure this out. Thanks to this I figured out my dictionary had references to a recordset that had been set to nothing!

Answer (score 0):

In regard to GUIDs, Access doesn't like them. [Michael Kaplan wrote about this years and years ago](http://trigeminal.com/usenet/usenet011.asp?1033). You might want to look into the StringFromGUID() and GUIDToString() functions.

And if there is not an external requirement that you use GUIDs, you should seriously consider getting rid of them entirely. They don't add anything at all that is necessary in 99.99% of Access applications.

Secondly, I've never used the scripting runtime's dictionary, but it really looks to me like it offers nothing you can't already get with a VBA custom collection. Can you outline what you're using it for, and how it is superior to the VBA collection? Also, why are you using early binding and not late binding?

Comment: I've already read Kaplan's article about Access and GUIDs - unfortunately, there is an external requirement to use these... however, since I'm storing the GUID as a basic string and my scripts will manage these, so Kaplan's arguments either don't apply or at least reduced to marginal issues.

Comment: wrt early vs late binding - I'm using it because this is what all the documentation I've so far uncovered says to use. Is there a reason why late binding would be preferred?

Comment: Late binding is always preferred because it makes your app much, much more stable in the production environment, where you don't have control over where external components are installed or whether or not they are properly registered. With late binding, your app can recover when the outside components are broken. With early binding, it's quite difficult to recover from a broken reference. All the professional Access developers I know of use late binding (though of course we often use early binding during development to get the advantage of Intellisense and compile-time checking).

Comment: Interesting, because after your comment, I read up on the differences - and the consensus seemed to be that one isn't outright better than the other - just better for some things, and not good for other things. That said - I'll probably switch to late-binding for production, maybe.

Comment: I wonder what articles you read. I know of not a single professional Access developer who considers early binding preferable. Now, there are those who pick and choose which components they will use it with. I don't use it with anything but the default 3 Access references, Access, VBA and DAO. Some people will set a reference to the Windows Scripting Runtime in order to use the File System Object, which nowadays is pretty dependably available. I won't do that (partly because it's so easy to use it with late binding), but most of that is left over from the days when some sysadmins disabled it.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=vba+late+binding+vs+early+binding&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: I've looked at the first two articles in the Google search results. The first is from MS and is hard to evaluate. The development environment makes all the difference in the world. Early binding for a VS project is a different animal than for an Access VBA project. The second is an article for WORD VBA, not Access, and includes a number of questionable statements, such as that late binding code is not compiled (I strongly doubt it) and will run considerable slower. Maybe that's true in Word, but it's NOT true in Access. Early binding is for the DEVELOPER, not for production (see next comment).

Comment: You can do late binding in an efficient way and in an inefficient way. That is, you could re-initialize your outside component each time you call it (inefficient) or you could initialize it the first time you call it and cache it (efficient). There is a slight different, apparently, in resolving the properties/methods of objects that are typed as objects instead of as their specific data type, but this likely only matters in the real world only when looping for 100s of 1000s of iterations.

Comment: Just looking through more of those articles, and it seems like the concensus on early vs. late binding in the VBA world outside of Access is different from that within Access. All the experienced Access developers I know of use late binding whereever appropriate, whereas it seems like Excel and Word VBA developers prefer early binding. I don't know if this has to do with the differences in the way the VBA project is compiled and managed in Word and Excel, or if it's just a local variant. For Access, I would say you'll find late binding a much more reliable approach for production use.

Comment: Old topic, but my two cents: Up until recently, I worked in an Office 2003 environment. Rolling out Office 2010 broke many references in tools I've created over the past few years. Late binding would have saved me a good deal of time in almost every instance.